# how do i stop a php script when ignore_user_abort(true); was set?

Tags: php

i attempted to make a script that would process an HUGE file, and i foolishly added the lines

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

to the top of the script. after i noticed the script was going at a pase that would take 1/3 of a year to finish. i attempted to stop it. i can tell its still going because its filling my error log with GB's of data every hour. and it says its from that script. How can i stop it? its been going for over a day now.

i dont have the power to restart the server itself, because its webhosting from bluehost

Comment: If you have access to the command line, you should run top and get the pid. then run: kill pid. You could also just send them a support request if you aren't comfortable doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluehost allows SSH access according to [their features page](http://www.bluehost.com/cgi/info/hosting_features), so log into that, use something like `top` to find the PHP process that is still running, and kill it (via `kill -9 <process id>`).

Comment: how do i find the process id? im not to familliar with bash

Comment: the command is "top" and it will bring up all current processes on the machine

Comment: bluehost also had a cpanel page to manage processes, i stopped it from there. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

`killall -9 %your_php_process_name%`. Or `ps aux | grep php` second column is a pid. Then type `kill -9 %pid%`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the SSH console, you can try to use the PHP `system` function. `top` will not work though. Try `ps` instead.

Comment: top is a command, that print in a new empty screen. This will not work, when you call it via system.

Comment: ohhh just read you're answer again and you were suggesting executing a fix via php (and you're right, top wouldn't be a good way to do that in php).